# Maven: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-plugin

Getting error while executing `sonar:sonar goal on maven project`

Tried using `sonar-maven-plugin` version `2.7.1` and `5.0`

Error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar failed: Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' 
in the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1'. 
A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/rtinfo/RuntimeInformation;
```

Comment: What's you maven version?

Comment: Maven version is m2e  1.3

Comment: That's m2e version. For mvn, try `mvn -version`

Comment: I have not installed maven locally. We are using eclipse plugin (Eclipse Maven plugin update site) - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Comment: You should install maven locally and run sonar scan on console and not from within Eclipse...

Comment: What is the version of the runtime embedded by m2e 1.3? Look like an old version. I just tried with m2e 1.6.2 (embedding Maven runtime 3.3.3) and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise, for your response.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise for your response. I installed maven 3.3.9 locally and tried maven build for my sonar plugin but it fails downloading required artifacts saying error  :  "NTLM authentication failed". (New problem alltogether) to overcome this issue I installed NTLM and set appropriate proxy but no luck and this time error is " Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Parent proxy unreacheable"

Comment: Hello Julien,  Yes I am using m2e 1.3. Tried installing m2e 1.6 (maven 3.3.9) unfortunately it throws an error  "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.2.20150902-0002) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.10.0' but it could not be found"   (tried installing SLF4j first then m2e 1.6 still error persist) could you please help me out in this?

Comment: You probably need a more recent version of Eclipse too.

Comment: Hello guys,  The issue is resolved. I used combination of Sonar 5.2, Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 (SR2) and  Maven-eclipse-plugin 1.6 (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.6).  recent version of eclipse allowed me to install m2e 1.6 and recent sonar version allowed me to execute sonar plugin without proxy error.

Comment: Thank you Julien, I could install m2e 1.6 with new eclipse version (Luna 4.4.2 - SR2) :)

Comment: You should answer your own question and after 2 days accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved.
 I used combination of Sonar 5.2, Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 (SR2) and Maven-eclipse-plugin 1.6 (download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.6). 
recent version of eclipse allowed me to install m2e 1.6 and recent sonar version allowed me to execute sonar plugin without proxy error.